# Higher-order functions

Tags: function, scheme, racket, higher-order-functions

given,

```
(define (reduce f id lis)
    (if (null? lis) id
      (f (car lis) (reduce f id (cdr lis)))))
```

The length of a list can be defined in terms of `reduce` (as opposed to
using a recursive definition from scratch) as

```
(define (mylength lis) (reduce  (lambda (x n) (+ 1 n)) 0 lis)).
```

Define the list function `mymap` (similar to `map`) that takes a unary function `uf` and a list `lis` in terms of reduce, that is, by determining the corresponding `f` and `id` in

```
(mymap uf lis) = (reduce f id lis),
```

Recall that `mymap` returns a list resulting from calling the function on every element in the input list such as `(mymap (lambda(x) (* 2 x)) '(1 2 3)) = (2 4 6)`.

A little Explanation to how this has been done would be helpful, rather than a blatant answer. Thank You.

Comment: What code have you written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have

```
(mymap uf lis) = (reduce f id lis) = 
 = (if (null? lis) id
     (f (car lis) (reduce f id (cdr lis))))
```

which must be equal to

```
 = (if null? lis) '()
     (cons (uf (car lis)) (mymap uf (cdr lis))))
```

matching the corresponding entities, we get

```
id == '()
```

and, since `(mymap uf lis) = (reduce f id lis)`, it is also `(mymap uf (cdr lis)) = (reduce f id (cdr lis))`, so we have

```
(f x y) = (cons (uf x) y)
```

Thus, we define

```
(define (mymap uf xs)   ; multiple `x`-es :)
  (reduce (lambda (x r)
             (cons .... r))
          '()
          xs ))
```

your `reduce` is a [right fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)): its combining function receives an element `x` of the argument list `xs`, and the recursive result of working on the rest of list, as `r`.

`r` has all the elements of the rest of `xs`, which were already mapped through `uf`. All that's left to do to combine the given element `x` with this recursive result `r`, is to `cons` the `(uf x)` onto `r`.

It should pose no problem now to complete the definition by writing the actual code in place of the dots `....` there.

Comment: can you please explain, the last statement, and how would you define mymap.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful.